# Error when upgrading from 4.3.4 5o 4.4 Error message

Tags: joomla-4.x, update

website working great before being asked to update Joomla to 4.4.  received this error message:
An error has occurred.
0 Return value of Joomla\CMS\Mail\MailerFactory::createMailer() must be an instance of Joomla\CMS\Mail\MailerInterface, instance of Joomla\CMS\Mail\Mail returned

Asked to return to Dashboard but not working. Last update was 3 months ago and didn't backup with this latest update.  Please advise.  Thanks

Comment: You will need to provide some more diagnostic for someone to be able to help you I think. If you switch on Error reporting to Maximum and Debug to Yes in the Global configuration the error will include the Stack Trace that will show which component or extension is calling the erroneous statement.